# How to Loop though BackColor change?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

absolute noob to coding here.

I'm trying to setup a form that opens from an action or a button click that loops through 2 colors with a timer

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

```
    Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255)
```

I've set the background color to red and I want it to flicker between red and white like an alarm.

Any help is much appreciated!

Tried using Do while Loop but it doesn't seem to work
or at least I don't understand the statement enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close.

Throw a `Timer` component into the form and configure it through the properties editor:

- Enabled = `true`.
- Interval to that of your choice (how long between color changes).

Then use the following in the `Tick` event:

```
If Me.BackColor = Color.Red Then
    Me.BackColor = Color.White
Else
    Me.BackColor = Color.Red
End if
```

Comment: This absolutely worked, thank you so much.